Will a dynamic list of choices in a Django model evaluate when the model is migrated or when a user tries to select a choice for a model?
Code
Let's say I have the following model:
class Course(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=48)

    YEAR_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(
            datetime.date.today().year-1, datetime.date.today().year+2
        )
    ]
    year = models.IntegerField(_('year'), choices=YEAR_CHOICES)

Question
Will the datetime.date.today() statements be evaluated right when the model is migrated, or will they be evaluated whenever the user accesses a form to set the year value for the Course model?
In other words, is my YEAR_CHOICES code above frozen to when I migrated my model or will it dynamically update as the years go by?

it should evaluate when you run code - so when user access page. But why don't you run it (today and tomorrow) to see if it changes when you use ie. datetime.date.today().day.

@furas, thanks for the suggestion since it led to the answer I posted. What I thought would run when the user accessed the page though actually only ran when the model was migrated.

Test results
I did some testing with minutes instead of years, and the results are pretty surprising:
Given this function...
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

def minute_choices_range():
    now_minute = now().minute
    return [(r, r) for r in range(
            now_minute-1, now_minute+2
        )
    ]

Constantly updated
(Time values that kept in sync with time a page was accessed)
class Course(models.Model):
    minute = models.IntegerField(choices=minute_choices_range)

Stuck at migration time
(Time values that were stuck at the time the model was migrated)
class Course(models.Model):
    minute = models.IntegerField(choices=minute_choices_range())


And given this function...
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

def current_min():
    return now().minute

Stuck at migration time
(Time values that were stuck at the time the model was migrated)
class Course(models.Model):
    MINUTE_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(
            current_min()-1, current_min()+2
        )
    ]

    minute = models.IntegerField(choices=MINUTE_CHOICES)


And this one I didn't have a function with, but it resulted in a "stuck time" as well (a time that is stuck at migration time)
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Course(models.Model):
    MINUTE_CHOICES = [(r, r) for r in range(
            now().minute-1, now().minute+2
        )
    ]

    minute = models.IntegerField(choices=MINUTE_CHOICES)


